# How to sniff HTTPS traffic of Android apps that ignore the system proxy setting?

Tags: android, sniffing, https-protocol

I saw a very similar question about this on macOS just 20hrs ago but I'm always needing to do this on Android and I keep forgetting the name of the app. So this is just for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Drony

Acts as a local VPN and redirects **all** traffic to a HTTP proxy. Its meant to be used with Orbot (TOR for Android) but can just as easily be used for this purpose using something like Fiddler to act as proxy server.

[Android App Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony&hl=en_GB)